# Android: How to set icon in title bar of Dialog activity?

Tags: android, android-manifest

I declared a dialog activity in my Manifest as follows:

```
<activity android:name=".myDialog"
              android:label="@string/title_dlg"
              android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_dialog_alert"
              android:exported="false"
              android:excludeFromRecents="true"
              android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Dialog">
```

However, only the title's text appears in the title bar and the icon appears to be ignored.
Is there a way to also show the icon in the title bar?

Comment: @ingsaurabh Sorry, I just noticed your question. The icon is `@android:drawable/ic_dialog_alert` in the Android resources. It is 48x48 pixels.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Use this after your `super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);` call:

```
requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_LEFT_ICON);
```

Then, set your `contentView(R.layout.youLayout);`
and then use this:

```
getWindow().setFeatureDrawableResource(Window.FEATURE_LEFT_ICON, android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_alert);
```

The order is important.

Answer (score 1):

I think using below line after `super` call will work

```
requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_CUSTOM_TITLE);
```

Keep in mind to place it before setting content view

Comment: Thanks, I tried your solution, but it replaced the title bar with a plain blue bar. Now there is no text and still no icon. :(

Comment: Of course it will not show you have to declare your custom title and specify it to the system